# How does $block->customerLoggedIn() work with Magento's cache?

Tags: magento2, cache, knockoutjs, full-page-cache

I see there are two ways Magento2 renders content in the header for logged-in vs logged-out customers.

1. With KnockoutJS in [header.phtml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml#L14)
2. With PHP in [customer.phtml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/templates/account/customer.phtml#L9)

Which is considered best practice?

The second approach seems better for faster rendering of the content but I would have thought it would have caused issues with [private-content](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html), but Magento uses it here, how does this not cause an issue with caching?

Answer (score 2):

It seems for [private content](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html) which is specific to a user, such as minicart, user-name etc. It is correct to use KnockoutJS/JavaScript to retrieve personalised data with Ajax requests or with Magento's [customerData](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js) JS component.
**This data cannot be cached on the server side.**
e.g. [header.phtml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml#L14)

However for content which is not unique to a specific user, but which is different per [page variation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/public-content.html#configure-page-variations).
**It can be cached on the server side**, with Magento's use of **HTTP context variables**. For example if a customer is logged in or not.
For example, this is what is happening with [customer.phtml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/templates/account/customer.phtml#L9) which is using [httpContext](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Block/Account/Customer.php#L52) to serve different content from the cache for requests origination from the same URL depending on if the user is logged in or not.

I found these blog posts helpful:
https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/cache-context-and-page-variations-in-magento-2/
https://www.interactiv4.com/e-commerce-en/almacenamiento-en-cache-en-magento-2-i4/?lang=en

As well as the documentation:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/public-content.html#configure-page-variations